# onnxruntime-c++ infer time usage is fluctuating when I input single sentence, but input a texts file is ok

Tags: c++, pytorch, bert-language-model, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm trying to deploy a bert model on onnxruntime-c++, but the infer time usage is confusing me. The time usage is **longer and fluctuating** when input is a single sentence from console real time than input a texts file with a lot of sentences.

The session initial code as follows:

```cpp
class BertModel
{
    public:
        BertModel(){};
        BertModel(const char* path)
        {              
            // initial tokenizer
            string vocab_path = join(path, "vocab.txt");
            pTokenizer = new FullTokenizer(vocab_path);

            // onnxruntime setup
            Ort::Env env(ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING, "small_bert_onnx"); //Set a  Env for this session,the Env holds the logging state used by all other objects.
            session_options.SetIntraOpNumThreads(1); //Sets the number of threads used to parallelize the execution within nodes. Default is 0 to let onnxruntime choose.
            session_options.SetInterOpNumThreads(1); //Sets the number of threads used to parallelize the execution of the graph (across nodes). Default is 0 to let onnxruntime choose.

            string model_path = join(path, "bert_model_quant.onnx");
            session = new Ort::Session(env, model_path.c_str(), session_options); //create a session,session is
            // session = new Ort::Session(env, model_path.c_str(), Ort::SessionOptions{ nullptr }); //don't do anyOptions

            size_t num_input_nodes = session->GetInputCount(); //  num_input_nodes size of model need,eg:(ids,mask,labels),your will get 3;
            char* input_name = session -> GetInputName(0, allocator);
            input_node_names = {input_name};
            output_node_names = {"logits"};
            // print input node types
            Ort::TypeInfo type_info = session -> GetInputTypeInfo(0);
            auto tensor_info = type_info.GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo();
            ONNXTensorElementDataType type = tensor_info.GetElementType();
            // print input shapes/dims
            input_node_dims = tensor_info.GetShape();
            cout << "session初始化成功" << endl;
        }

        string join(const char *a, const char *b);
        vector<long> textTokenizer(string text);
        int predicts(string text);

    private:
        FullTokenizer* pTokenizer;
        Ort::SessionOptions session_options;
        std::vector<int64_t> input_node_dims;
        std::vector<const char*> output_node_names;
        Ort::AllocatorWithDefaultOptions allocator; // allocator
        std::vector<const char*> input_node_names;
        Ort::Session* session;
};
```

My predicts function as follows:

```cpp
int BertModel::predicts(string text)
{   
    vector<long> input_tensor_values = textTokenizer(text);

    auto memory_info = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtArenaAllocator, OrtMemTypeDefault);

    input_node_dims[0]=1;
    input_node_dims[1]=input_tensor_values.size();

    Ort::Value input_tensor = Ort::Value::CreateTensor<long>(memory_info,input_tensor_values.data(), 
                              input_tensor_values.size(), input_node_dims.data(), input_node_dims.size());
    assert(input_tensor.IsTensor());

    //outputs from session run is vector<Value>
    auto output_tensors = session -> Run(Ort::RunOptions{nullptr}, 
                                      input_node_names.data(), 
                                      &input_tensor,
                                      1,
                                      output_node_names.data(),
                                      1);

    // output_tensors 2, logitspreds
    // onnlogitsfloatfloat
    float* floatarr = output_tensors[0].GetTensorMutableData<float>();
    int res = max_element(floatarr, floatarr + 3) - floatarr;
    return res;
}
```

My code to infer **single sentence** is showing as follows,the input is **get from console real time**:

```cpp
    string text;
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "enter your input" << endl;
        getline(cin, text);
        high_resolution_clock::time_point beginTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
        int res = model.predicts(text);
        high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
        milliseconds timeInterval = std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(endTime - beginTime);
        cout << "predict result:" << res << endl;
        cout << "time spent:" << timeInterval.count() << "ms" << endl;
    }
```

```
你给我想没有包子铺的你也灯关的水都关了新的利润都被人骨的肌
predict result:1
time spent:16ms
enter your input
你给我想没有包子铺的你也灯关的水都关了新的利润都被人骨的肌
predict result:1
time spent:16ms
enter your input
你给我想没有包子铺的你也灯关的水都关了新的利润都被人骨的肌
predict result:1
time spent:14ms
enter your input
你给我想没有包子铺的你也灯关的水都关了新的利润都被人骨的肌
predict result:1
time spent:8ms
enter your input
你给我想没有包子铺的你也灯关的水都关了新的利润都被人骨的肌
predict result:1
time spent:15ms
enter your input
你给我想没有包子铺的你也灯关的水都关了新的利润都被人骨的肌
predict result:1
time spent:8ms
enter your input
你给我想没有包子铺的你也灯关的水都关了新的利润都被人骨的肌
predict result:1
time spent:13ms
```

My code to infer a **texts file** is showing as follows:

```cpp
    string input_path = "../../test0711.txt";
    string output_path = "../../test0711_result.txt";
    ifstream input_file(input_path);
    ofstream output_file(output_path);
    if (!input_file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Could not open the file - '"
             << input_path << "'" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!output_file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Could not open the file - '"
             << output_path << "'" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int time_spent = 0;
    int seq_nums = 0;

    string line;
    while (getline(input_file, line))
    {   
        high_resolution_clock::time_point beginTime = high_resolution_clock::now(); //start time
        int res = model.predicts(line); //predicts single sentence
        high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime = high_resolution_clock::now(); //end time
        milliseconds timeInterval = std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(endTime - beginTime); //spent time
        cout << "bytes length of this sentence:" << line.size()/3 << endl;
        cout << "predict result:" << res << endl;
        cout << "time spent:" << timeInterval.count() << "ms" << endl;
        output_file << line << '\t' << res << '\t' << timeInterval.count() << "ms" << endl;
        time_spent += timeInterval.count();
        seq_nums++;
    }
    input_file.close();
    output_file.close();
```

```
你知道什么是版权问题吗就是他们就是这个 1   6ms
北石店 2   3ms
我要去新街口  0   4ms
导航到向阳小区 0   4ms
只想守护你   0   3ms
将车道偏离预警开关打开 0   4ms
导航到南海意库 0   4ms
导航去1号公馆 0   4ms
1米制的恭喜发财    1   4ms
你给我想没有包子铺的你也灯关的水都关了新的利润都被人骨的肌   1   8ms
你吃不吃粑粑  1   4ms
导航去深圳湾创新科技中心    0   4ms
个性也没看就行了    1   4ms
三好听你就三个1390这个都是套餐5万双送给您的    1   6ms
```

Obviously,time usage is proportional to length of sentences when I input a texts file.
So,why the bug occur and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to only measure the time the call to Run takes. You're including pre and post processing like the tokenization in your timing so it's not an accurate measure of how long ONNX Runtime took.

ONNX Runtime has some logic to track memory usage required for a request so that next time input with the same shape is received it can allocate a single block. That may affect latency as requests that can use a single block should be faster. It's possible to turn off with https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/api/c/struct_ort_1_1_session_options.html#a85495cc117b54771cb4d7632753532f0

Have you tested with exactly the same input in the file as what you're providing from the console? The less differences between the two the better.